# How to solve the error Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 in python?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am trying to build a model for recognizing bangla sign language.But when I am
trying to fit my model it gives me error.

I have added my code below.

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import os
 import cv2
 from tqdm import tqdm

 DATADIR = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Dataset/BSL Alphabet'

 CATEGORIES =['1','2','3','4','5','6','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Z1','Z2','Z3',]



for category in CATEGORIES:  # do dogs and cats
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
       for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image
          img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img),
                           cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

       # convert to array

           plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')  # graph it
           plt.show()  # display!
           break  # we just want one for now so break
    break



  batch_size = 32
  img_height = 100
  img_width = 100
  train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATADIR,validation_split=0.2,subset='training',seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  )
  val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATADIR,validation_split=0.2,subset='validation',seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  )
  AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

  train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
  num_classes = 36

  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(100,
                       100, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
      tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(84, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'),
      ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
    loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=3)
```

The error comes when I try to this model.
Error looks like below:
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
2   train_ds,
3   validation_data=val_ds,
----> 4   epochs=3
5 )

```
9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:787 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1037 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:383 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1037 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/pooling.py:360 call
        data_format=conv_utils.convert_data_format(self.data_format, 4))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py:4783 max_pool
        name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py:5344 max_pool
        data_format=data_format, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:750 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:601 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3569 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:2042 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1883 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for '{{node sequential_3/max_pooling2d_22/MaxPool}} = MaxPool[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", explicit_paddings=[], ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]](sequential_3/batch_normalization_22/FusedBatchNormV3)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,256].
```

Comment: You pooling layer is trying to pool data and reduce the dimension of output by the factor of 2 in both axes. What might be happening is that the input to the layer has one of dimensions of size 1 so this causes the problem. What is the size of your input? What is the output of `model.summary()`?

Comment: By my estimate, with your 100*100 input by the fifth MaxPooling layer you have an input of size 1*1 which won't work. You have too many convolutional blocks. I also doubt you'll need a hidden Dense layer here.